# xcode 4 -- is there a way to echo stuff in config files?

Tags: xcode4, clang, build-system, xcconfig

I am working on a deeply nested Xcode project that uses config files to control settings.  There are projects within projects within projects.  Is it possible to echo stuff in the config files?  In trying to debug it, I am finding it would be really helpful to see what some of the variables are.  Like BUNDLE_LOADER, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, and so on.

I am aware that I can get some of these things by reading the log file.  But that's a real pain!

EDIT: to clarify, these are the build time variables that are controlled by the config files.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an alert view with the items and load it ..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // get your vairables from the defaults
    NSString *variable1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"variable1"];
    NSString *variable2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"variable2"];

    // build your alert mesage
    NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the variables you are looking for are %@ and %@",variable1,variable2];

    // create the alert view for display
    UIAlertView *alertmsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Variables:" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    // display the alert
    [alertmsg show];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: my initial comment is for default variables, but all you would have to change is the source for the variables, which you were already working on doing to display them in the log.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want stuff to echo at build time, showing the build settings as determined by the config files.